# How to iterate and divide two list by each other in haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I have a list A  = [3,5,6,8,9]
and list B = [1,2,..] infinite list

B remains same but A changes and in short I want to return a list C as True or False

```
-- x from a and y from b
if mod x y == 0:
 then c = True
else False
```

So in the end the goal is to return a list c which tells if element at particular index is divisible by its index starting from 1.

Comment: [find your function at hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20c)%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Bb%5D%20-%3E%20%5Bc%5D)

Comment: Why did you delete this question after receiving an answer that you said was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want `` zipWith (\x y -> x `mod` y == 0) a b ``.

Comment: hey this is helpful Thanks, I was using very complex method where I was zipping with a custom function with if and else condition.

Comment: @Aavesh Of course it is possible, you can just try all possibilities: `cubeSum x = [ (n1,n,m) | n1 <- [0..x], n <- [0..x], m <- [0..x], n1 ^ 3 + n ^ 3 + m ^ 3 == x]`. The questions you are asking do not show much effort on your part. Please spend some more time trying to solve these problems yourself or search for existing learning materials e.g. those listed on https://haskell.org/documentation.

Comment: this seems like a good solution, I was reading the cube sum wikipedia in python to reach something similar. I am suing backtracking will elt you know how it goes. Thanks.